# How to disable automatic registration of schema on the Azure Schema Registry in Kafka Connect scenario?

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, avro

Does anyone know whether it is possible to setup the source connector in Kafka Connect scenarios so that it does not automatically register schemas on the Azure Schema Registry?

I ask since I'm currently using com.microsoft.azure.schemaregistry.kafka.avro.AvroConverter class as a value converter in the source connector. I'm using Kafka Connect to ingest data from postgres database to a Kafka topic and I'm storing schemas in Azure Schema Registry.

Automatic schema registration is not the best practice, hence I would like to avoid it.
As far as I can see auto.register.schemas option was removed from configuration of connectors so I am interested; is there any alternative way to prevent connector from automatically registering schemas?
This is Azure Schema Registry for Kafka repo https://github.com/Azure/azure-schema-registry-for-kafka in which class AvroConverter is implemented.

This is the configuration of my source connector:

```
{
 "name": "jdbc-postgresql-avro-connector-azure",
 "config": {
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "value.converter": "com.microsoft.azure.schemaregistry.kafka.avro.AvroConverter",
  "value.converter.schema.registry.url": {schemaRegistryUrl},
  "value.converter.schema.group": "postgreskafkaschemagroup",
  "value.converter.tenant.id": {tenantId},
  "value.converter.client.id": {clientId},
  "value.converter.client.secret": {clientSecret},
  "connection.url": {postgresConnectionUrl},
  "connection.user": {user},
  "connection.password": {password},
  "connection.attempts": 3,
  "mode": "incrementing",
  "query": "SELECT * FROM users",
  "table.types": "TABLE",
  "topic.prefix": "users",
  "incrementing.column.name": "id"
 }
}
```

As I said, firstly I tried to set value.converter.auto.register.schemas to false and this configuration would work in a scenario where I am producing messages to Kafka topic and where Kafka producer is using KafkaAvroSerializer as serializer class.

Unfortunately, it seems that auto.regiser.schemas does not exists as a configuration option for AvroConverter which is used in Kafka Connect scenarios?

I would like to know is there any way to setup connector configuration so it does not automatically register schemas.

Answer (score 0):

Converters still use serializers. The configs may or may not be passed though to the serializer, however. Or [they are hardcoded](https://github.com/Azure/azure-schema-registry-for-kafka/commit/afcd33b85238c0f5336ed51ead00c6258252d084#diff-2c39de02f726461694822607ff083e1e6fd40a3256c51afac275d6811a98badfR75). Based on that PR, no,  it is not possible without modifying the source code or trying to use reflection (not possible in Connect API).

Luckily, you could clone that repo, make the edits, then `mvn package` and copy the converter JARs over to `plugin.path`
connect property, as you're probably already doing.

---

You can find all possible configs for the Converter [in the source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-schema-registry-for-kafka/blob/master/java/avro-converter/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/schemaregistry/kafka/connect/avro/AvroConverterConfig.java) for the class you're using.

Similarly, you can look at the Serializer class [config](https://github.com/Azure/azure-schema-registry-for-kafka/blob/master/java/avro/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/schemaregistry/kafka/avro/KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.java#L25) to see auto registration defaults to disabled

> was removed from configuration

By who/what? Why not add it back, even if it defaults to false?

> this configuration would work in a scenario where I am producing messages to Kafka topic and where Kafka producer is using KafkaAvroSerializer

You wouldn't prefix the config with `value.converter` when using a producer

> Unfortunately, it seems that auto.regiser.schemas does not exists

It does, but you've mistyped it there

Comment: Thank you for answer!
Yes auto.register.schemas exists as a KafkaAvroSerializer configuration, but it is not used in AvroConverter.
In AvroConverter implementation serializer is created on line 73 and there autoRegisterSchema is set to true.
Meanwhile, in KafkaAvroSerializer implementation serializer is created on line 50 and autoRegisterSchemas method uses as an argument value from auto.register.schemas configuration.
This is why it seems to me that there is no way to disable auto register of schemas when using AvroConverter.

Comment: Right. Reading through the repo, I see no configure function called to pass extra configs to the serializer. Compare to Confluent - https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/avro-converter/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/avro/AvroConverter.java#L80 +  https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/avro-converter/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/avro/AvroConverter.java#L169